# Has this nuclear reaction analogy been formalised for multithreading?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing

I was wondering whether this multithreading concept which draws analogy between nuclear reactions and threaded programs has been formalised ?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_computation

Nuclear computation suggests that a program's thread can experience fission to generate more computational threads and various threads can experience fusion to converge multiple threads into one.

Perhaps it has a different name in academic circles ?

Some requirements of interest are the following (which can be implemented with futexes rather then mutexes) :

- lockless
- parallel
- ordered
- light weight
- low latency

Comment: How's creating/disposing of threads better than thread pool and Future patterns? Why is this a thing at all?

Comment: Can they be ultra low latency and lockless ? I updated the question to include some requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the lead Dariusz, it seems concurrency patterns are the thing. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_pattern